# How to delete quotes from data read from .csv file?

Tags: python, file, csv, import

I am trying to read several `.csv` files from a directory with the following code and then store each line of output result as a row of a matrix:

```
import os, fnmatch
import csv
listOfFiles = os.listdir('C:/Users/m/Desktop/csv_files')  
pattern = "*.csv"  
for entry in listOfFiles:  
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(entry, pattern):
        with open(entry, newline='') as csvfile:
            spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            for line in spamreader:
                print(line)
```

The output of the above code is like this:

```
['DATE', 'OPEN', 'HIGH', 'LOW', 'CLOSE', 'PRICE', 'YCLOSE', 'VOL', 'TICKS']
['13950309', '1000000.00', '1000000', '1000000', '1000000.00', '1000000.00', '1000000', '2100000', '74']
['13950326', '1050000.00', '1050010', '1050000', '1050001.00', '1050000.00', '1000000', '1648', '5']
['13950329', '1030200.00', '1060000', '1030200', '1044474.00', '1042265.00', '1050001', '28469', '108']
```

But I like to delete quotes from data and have rows like this:

```
[13971116, 1020002.00, 1020002, 1020000, 1020001.00, 1020000.00, 1020002, 107, 4]
```

And store them as rows of a matrix. How can I do that?(I have `numpy` library for matrix working).

Comment: There are no quotes in `line`. You see quotes because you are dumping a python list (`line`) to the output. Use `print(line[0])` and you'll see it's just the number.

Comment: I changed the code like what you said but the result was a number per line and destroyed the structure I have copied in my post.

Comment: Ah I see, it's not about the quotes but you do want to convert the strings to numbers. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following:

```py
import os, fnmatch
import csv
listOfFiles = os.listdir('C:/Users/m/Desktop/csv_files')  
pattern = "*.csv"  
for entry in listOfFiles:  
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(entry, pattern):
        with open(entry, newline='') as csvfile:
            spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            for line in spamreader:
                try:
                    print(list(map(float, line)))
                except:
                    print(line)
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say the first line of my `.csv` file is this line: `DATE OPEN HIGH LOW CLOSE PRICE YCLOSE VOL TICKS` . How can I skip reading this line of file? Because it gives me "SyntaxError: can't assign to operator" error when try your code.

Comment: I have modified the solution, can you check now

Comment: Thank you, now it works. May you help me please to save read data to a `numpy` array as a matrix? I also don't need the first line of cvs files(strings)

Comment: I would recommend you to use a library named `pandas`, it will save you a lot of time. Even the CSV reading, writing, analyzing, etc. everything can be done using `pandas` library

Comment: I have it too, but I am not familiar with python and just use it for ML purpose. So I got the above code from someone! If you can change the code to pandas version. What I need is reading a .csv file, and save it as numpy.array like a matrix to work on it. I also don't need the first line(strings).

Comment: If you think it's better to create a new question for that purpose let me know

Comment: do you want all your csv's data to a single numpy array, or multiple numpy array's based on different csv files?

Comment: I created a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54691250/how-to-read-specific-rows-columns-of-a-csv-file-and-storing-them-as-a-numpy-mat

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `line` is already a list of strings-- no quotes. To get a matrix of rows of numbers, write:

```
with open(entry, newline='') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    data_matrix = list([ float(n) for n in row ] for row in spamreader)
```

and you're done.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say the first line of my .csv file is this line: DATE OPEN HIGH LOW CLOSE PRICE YCLOSE VOL TICKS . How can I skip reading this line of file? Because it gives me "ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'DATE' " error when I try your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your values doesn't contain quotes.
Quotes here are just string delimiters which indicate that values are strings.

If you need numbers you need to **cast** values to the desired type, for example if all your values are integers you can cast values using `int(value)`

Your code will be:

```
import os, fnmatch
import csv
listOfFiles = os.listdir('C:/Users/m/Desktop/csv_files')  
pattern = "*.csv"  
for entry in listOfFiles:  
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(entry, pattern):
        with open(entry, newline='') as csvfile:
            spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            for line in spamreader:
                print(line)
                # create a new list casting all line values to integers
                line_ints = [int(val) for val in line]
                print(line_ints)
```